# Angular: enable router scrolling selectively?

Tags: angular

I am working with Keycloak/OAuth2, which sends the JWT token via hash-fragment in the URI-redirect. In Angular this is problematic when working with anchor-router-scrolling. On redirects from the external login-page back to Angular, I get the error:

```
state=LONG.JWT.TOKEN is not a valid selector
at BrowserViewportScroller.push.../../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js
.BrowserViewportScroller.scrollToAnchor
```

removing the token inside a guard like this does not solve the problem because then the login process is aborted:

```
@Injectable()
export class StateFromUrlRemovalGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (route.fragment && route.fragment.startsWith('state=')) {
        this.router.navigate(state);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

So is there any way to make router execute the scrolling only selectively in some modules/components and not others, eg to make it not think that state= is a querySelector? My routerconfig (which is only possible forRoot in AppModule, not in lazy child-modules; they accept only one argument, eg the routes) looks like this:

```
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
scrollOffset: [0, 50]
```

Comment: I think you are using scrollTo function and using "state=LONG.JWT.TOKEN" as a selector, which does't look like a valid selector, please try to debug this thing.

Comment: @ArpitMeena it is obvious that it is not a selector. I wrote that in my post. But it is not me who is using it but the framework